# How to use both Powermock and Easymock?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

in my methodtobetested() is having a static method call and object to be injected. so i am trying to use both powermock and easymock. while running with
PowerMockRunner EasyMock is not mocking the object.

I am trying like below but i am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock:

Below is my sample code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CommandHelper.class)

public class TasksOfProcessTest {

    @Mock
    private EntitySet mockEntitySet;

@Mock
private DataServices mockDataServices;
//@Mock
private WorkflowInterface myProcess = PowerMock.createMock(WorkflowInterfaceImpl.class); 


 @Test
    public void testGetTasksByProcessInstanceId() {

        HashMap queryParam = new HashMap();
    queryParam.add("ProcessInstanceId", "4");

    TaskInstance expecttaskInstance = new TaskInstance("69", "Visual Confirmation of cust.docs.",
            "EB.CHECK.DOCUMENT,DOCUMENT.CHECK I F3", "CUST.ONBOARDING", "59", "SUCCESS", null, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    List<TaskInstance> taskInstanceList = new ArrayList<TaskInstance>();
    taskInstanceList.add(expecttaskInstance);
    ResourceState state = (PowerMockito.mock(ResourceState.class));
    when(state.getEntityName()).thenReturn("Task");

    MyContext context = new MyContext(PowerMockito.mock(UriInfo.class),PowerMockito.mock(HttpHeaders.class),new List<String>(),
            queryParam,
            state, 
            testMetadata);

    try {

     // Mocks configuration
        reset(myProcess); 
        expect(myProcess.getTasksByProcessInstanceId("4", statusList)).andReturn(taskInstanceList).times(1);
        replay(myProcess);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(CommandHelper.class);
        PowerMockito.when(CommandHelper.getEntitySet("Task", mockEdmDataServices)).thenReturn(createMockEdmEntitySet());

        Result result = command.methodToBeTested(context);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you try to use two mock library simultaneously? Mocking is full of MAGIC and different kind of magic usually don't mix well.

Comment: I am ready to use only powermock but i dont know how to inject an object that is created, internalized & used in the test method. Your answer will be greatly helpful. Thanks

Comment: Try to rewrite your cofe to using only `PowerMock` and ask concrete question if something not working.

Comment: Please, read the [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/EasyMock)